# Laravel eloquent slow loading data

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-9

i have a piece of code here

```
  $shorturls = ShortUrl::withCount("clicks")->where([["url_id", "=", $id->id], ["user_id", "=", Auth::id()]])
        ->orderBy("clicks_count", "desc")
        ->paginate(10);
```

this query runs in 6000ms (1 million rows of data)

when i comment `orderBy` it will around 300-500ms

(`Shorturl` model has many `clicks`)

i want a way to have a field in my short url named `clicks_count` to make this query faster.

Answer (score 0):

Since you order by the clicks_count, mysql has to count the clicks for all rows in ShortUrl (1 million) before it can order.
Not just the 10 paginated.

You could:

1. Make sure that the ShortUrl<->clicks relationsship has correct indexes in the db. By looking at the query I would guess the field in the clicks table that should be indexed would be named "url_id".
2. Even though it is indexed it could still take some time. So another ide could be to denormalize the count, and then for each click, you increment a field in the short_urls table. That way it should not have to count on read.

If that not helps, then please provide your table structure including indexes for both short_urls and clicks tables.

Comment: thank you for your comment, i have a question : there is any way to define a field named clicks_count in my short urls table, like this ? clicks_count = select count from clicks table where url_id = id

Comment: You would have to make a trigger in MySQL for the clicks table to do that. Alternativly you could create a async job in Laravel that is fired for each click on URL's (or periodically if precision is not vital). Stored generated columns (columns that update themselves) are not able to use data from other columns - only from the row itself. So they cannot be used to auto generate the value in the short_urls tables.

Comment: Did you make sure, you had an index on url_id in the clicks table? That would be the first thing to check!

Comment: yes i checked and i have index. i want to trying mysql views, to have a column like clicks_count, do you think this is a good way ?

Comment: Views would unfortunatly not help you, because they are not materialized and updated on write, but instead evaluated on read. So the performance problem would still be there.